# Visual Basic Nullable Value Types Equality

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Why doesn't this print out true?

```
>         Dim test1 As Decimal? = Nothing
>         Dim test2 As Decimal? = 5D
> 
>         If (test1 <> test2) Then
>             Console.WriteLine("true")
>         End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out. I need to do

IF(Not test1.Equals(test2))

Answer (score 4):

Unlike C#, the not equals operator doesn't work for this.  Instead, use `Nullabe.Equals()`

```
Dim test1 As Decimal? = Nothing
Dim test2 As Decimal? = 5D

If (Nullable.Equals(test1, test2) = False) Then
    Console.WriteLine("not equal")
Else
    Console.WriteLine("equal")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing a value to a null value generally returns `False`.

The values can't be compared as one is a lack of value, so both `=` and `<>` operators will return `False`.

Comment: This a true statement of how VB works, but in C# != would return True.  Inconsistant and confusing.